# range of probability $P(Y\cap Z)$ , If there events probability given.

Tags: probability

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be $3$ events such that $P(X)=1/5$ and $P(Y)=P(Z)=3/5$ and $P(Y/X)=1/2$ and  $X,Z$ are mutually exclusive. Then range of $P(Y\cap Z)$ is

What i try ::

If $X,Z$ are mutually exclusive. Then $X\cap Z=\phi\Longrightarrow P(X\cap Z)=0$

And $\displaystyle P(Y/X)=\frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(X)}\Longrightarrow P(X\cap Z)=\frac{1}{10}$

And $P(Y\cap Z)=P(Y)+P(Z)-P(Y \cup Z)$

$\displaystyle P(Y\cap Z)=\frac{6}{5}-P(Y\cup Z)$

Know i did not understand how do i solve further.

Please explain how do i find upper and lower bound for $P(Y\cap Z)$. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's helpful to draw the Venn Diagram out.

What we want is the bound of $b$. What we know is

$$a+b={1\over 2}$$
$$b+c={3\over 5}$$
$$a+b+c \leq {4\over 5}$$
$$a,b,c \geq 0$$

Therefore $${1\over 2}\geq b\geq {3\over 10}$$

Comment: Can u please explain me how we get $a+b=1/2$ and $b+c=3/5.$. Thanks

Comment: $a+b={1\over 2}$ because the whole $Y$ region is $3\over 5$, given by $P(Y)={3\over 5}$ and the left $X$-intersection region is $1\over 10$ as you calculated. Therefore $a+b$ region is ${3\over 5} - {1\over 10}={1\over 2}$. $b+c={3\over 5}$ is given by $P(Z)$.

Comment: Thanks cr001. Please also explain me how we get $a+b+c\leq 4/5.$ Thanks

Comment: It's because the two $1\over 10$ regions and $a,b,c$ are all mutually exclusive and their sum cannot exceed one.

Comment: The benefit of venn diagram is that you can easily break the events into mutually exclusive parts and visualize them.

Comment: Thanks cr001 got it. Please explain me how u got $b\leq 1/2$

Comment: Thanks so much got it.